# extracting strings from cellarray using regexp - matlab

Tags: matlab

```
c = {'The quick'; 'brown fox'; 'jumps over'; 'the lazydog'};

r = {'.*quick', '.*over'};
```

I'm trying to extract the strings `'The quick'` and `'jumps over'` using `regexp`. I thought this would work:

```
regexp(c, r, 'match')
```

But I'm getting the error message:

```
Error using regexp
Multiple strings and patterns given must have the same quantity.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45-2):

> If str and expression are string arrays or cell arrays, they must have the same dimensions.

so to achieve your desired result, use a single pattern with alternation:

```matlab
c = {'The quick'; 'brown fox'; 'jumps over'; 'the lazydog'};
r = '.*quick|.*over';
regexp(c, r, 'match')
```

Answer (score 2):

@Paolo's answer is perfectly good and correct, but I would encourage you to use [MATLAB's `string` type](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) rather than cell arrays of char-vectors. Also, use [`pattern`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pattern.html) rather than `regexp`, and get something like this:

```matlab
% Use string arrays rather than cellstr for loads of great reasons
c = ["The quick", "brown fox", "jumps over", "the lazydog"];
% Make a combined pattern matching either "quick" OR "over"
want = pattern("quick") | pattern("over");
% Find which entries in |c| contain the wanted pattern
tf = contains(c, want);
% Show those entries
c(tf)
```

Comment: Or if using in-built alternatives to regex, just use `endsWith` or `contains` with cells of chars, which would work with OP's example with minimal changes

Comment: In fact, that code works perfectly well when `c` is a `cellstr` rather than a `string` - but given the choice, new code is much better off using `string` rather than `cellstr`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I was looking at `want` not `c`, the OP already has something like `want = {'quick','over'}` which would work fine with `contains` without the intermediate step of using `pattern()`, i.e. `contains(c,{'quick','over'})`. Having said that, `contains(c,["quick","over"])` would also work, does `pattern` offer anything "extra" here?

Comment: Yeah probably not in fact. (I just really like `pattern`)